# Bind a java class as a closure into a groovy-script

Tags: java, binding, groovy, closures

Is it possible to bind a closure written in java into a groovy-script. Is there an interface or something to implement so i can provide a closure?

Something like this?

```
public class Example implements Closure {
   public void closure(Object... args) {
       System.out.println(args[0]);
   }
}
```

Bind this into the groovyscript.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.put("example", new Example());
groovyScriptEngine.run("foo.groovy", binding)
```

and use it in the `foo.groovy` like this:

```
example("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done a bit of messing around and came up with this:

Example.java

```
import groovy.lang.Closure ;

public class Example extends Closure {
  public Example( Object owner, Object thisObject ) {
    super( owner, thisObject ) ;
  }

  public Example( Object owner ) {
    super( owner ) ;
  }

  public Object call( Object params ) {
    System.out.println( "EX: " + params ) ;
    return params ;
  }
}
```

foo.groovy:

```
example( 'Hello World' )
```

and test.groovy:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine

Binding binding = new Binding()
binding.example = new Example( this )
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( [ '.' ] as String[] )
gse.run( "foo.groovy", binding )
```

Then, I compile the java code:

```
javac -cp ~/Applications/groovy/lib/groovy-1.7.1.jar Example.java
```

Run the Groovy code:

```
groovy -cp . test.groovy
```

And get the output:

```
EX: Hello World
```

**edit**

The [groovy.lang.Closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) class defines 3 variants of call:

```
Object call()
Object call(Object arguments)
Object call(Object[] args)
```

I override the second one, but depending on your use-case, you might need any or all of the others

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Note, you can also null the owner Script in Closure Implementation, so you can bind it from Java.

Comment: Is it also possible to bind a external Groovy closure into a Groovy Script?

Comment: you mean bind a script into a script?

Comment: Excellent.  That line "GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( ['.'] as String[] )"  is pretty slick. Thanks.